# Galilei group and Constrained QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, hamiltonian, constrained-dynamics, galilean-relativity

Let's assume spin-0 for simplicity.

So far as I understand the issue, the Galilei simmetries constraints the possible hamiltonians of a quantum systems so that the only possible interactions of a particle with the external world are given by a vector and a scalar potential.

On the other hand, the equation for a particle confined to move in a 2D surface comes from generalizing the Laplace operator to include the information about the surface.

Taking into account that the confinement comes from a interaction (like an electron moving inside a surface made of graphene), The question is

What is the relation between the above two apparently different results?

Answer (score 0):

The equation of motion for a particle in a 2D potential is non-fundamental as it emerges as an effective theory from some, more fundamental, interactions. In the example of the constrained particle, these "more fundamental" interactions are described by a Quantum Field Theory for the graphene plus the particle moving on top it.